Macerator: pee vs. poo
Our trilevel home is not working well for us in our old age: our more frequent need to urinate and the need to go either upstairs or downstairs to bathrooms is becoming tedious.  There is no bathroom on middle level where our living room and dining room are located -- and where we tend to hang out.  We are thinking a macerator toilet in the laundry room on that floor.
To avoid excessive/needless use of the blades, I wondered if there is a style that allows one to flip the switch for solids rather than run it frequently just for liquid waste, which I assume serves no real purpose?
Also, anyone have a macerator toilet and have any advice?

If a regular toilet upstairs and downstairs, a regular toilet should work.  If laundry room is between the two bathrooms.  A macerator should only be needed if the laundry is on the other side of the house from the bathrooms.

A laundry room connects to the drain/sewer system too.. While it might be served by just a 2" line, chances are typically good that a 3" or 4" line with capacity for a toilet is not far away. I guess a macerator model has the advantage that it might be possible to attach to the existing sink or clothes washer pipes with really no remodel/re-pipe at all.
